# how get value cell use jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a datatable with checkboxes, I want to display table array but the "PRIME" field is not displayed ,in my example I want to display the values of PRIME cells that means 0,help plz.
here is my datatable :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#check_all').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked', true)) {
      $(".checkbox").prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $(".checkbox").prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
  $('.checkbox').on('click', function() {
    if ($('.checkbox:checked').length == $('.checkbox').length) {
      $('#check_all').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $('#check_all').prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
  
  // jquery code for display array :
  $("#hide").click(function() {
    var items = [];
    $("tr").each(function(i, r) {
      if (i > 0 && $(r).find("input").first().prop("checked")) {
        items.push({
          "nom": r.cells[1].innerText,
          "matricule": r.cells[2].innerText,
          "adresse": r.cells[3].innerText,
          "prime": r.cells[4].innerText
        })
      }
    });
    console.log(items);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered" id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th><input type="checkbox" id="check_all"></th>
    <th>nom</th>
    <th>matricule</th>
    <th>adresse</th>
    <th>prime</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
    <td>najib</td>
    <td>52</td>
    <td>tihit</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="prime" class="form-control" value="0"></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
    <td>adil</td>
    <td>62</td>
    <td>tagmast</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="prime" class="form-control" value="0"></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
    <td>hajar</td>
    <td>72</td>
    <td>tizgui</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="prime" class="form-control" value="0"></td>

  </tr>
</table>
<div class="form-group col-md-offset-5 ">
  <button class="btn btn-success add-all" type="submit" id="hide">Pointage men</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to replace `$(r).find("input").first()` with `$(r).find(".checkbox")`? You're using that earlier in your code, so be consistent.

Comment: thx for u answer ,I replace INPUT by checkbox but it does not work

Comment: `r.cells[4].innerText` should be `r.cells[4].value`.

Comment: Or `$(r).find("[name=prime]").val()`

Comment: Try to avoid hard-coding column numbers like that. I moved some columns around in a table recently, it it broke something else, because the other code had specific column numbers in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that there is an input inside the table, so you can access it with `.val()`.  In my example below, I use a jQuery selector on the table input, then use a jQuery find to get the input element, and then get its value with .val().

`"prime": $(r.cells[4]).find('input').val()`

Here's a working example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#check_all').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked', true)) {
      $(".checkbox").prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $(".checkbox").prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
  $('.checkbox').on('click', function() {
    if ($('.checkbox:checked').length == $('.checkbox').length) {
      $('#check_all').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $('#check_all').prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
  
  // jquery code for display array :
  $("#hide").click(function() {
    var items = [];
    $("tr").each(function(i, r) {
      if (i > 0 && $(r).find("input").first().prop("checked")) {
        items.push({
          "nom": r.cells[1].innerText,
          "matricule": r.cells[2].innerText,
          "adresse": r.cells[3].innerText,
          "prime": $(r.cells[4]).find('input').val()
        })
      }
    });
    console.log(items);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered" id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th><input type="checkbox" id="check_all"></th>
    <th>nom</th>
    <th>matricule</th>
    <th>adresse</th>
    <th>prime</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
    <td>najib</td>
    <td>52</td>
    <td>tihit</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="prime" class="form-control" value="0"></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
    <td>adil</td>
    <td>62</td>
    <td>tagmast</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="prime" class="form-control" value="0"></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
    <td>hajar</td>
    <td>72</td>
    <td>tizgui</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="prime" class="form-control" value="0"></td>

  </tr>
</table>
<div class="form-group col-md-offset-5 ">
  <button class="btn btn-success add-all" type="submit" id="hide">Pointage men</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few errors and improvements that can be made to your code. See below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#check_all').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked', true)) {
      $(".checkbox").prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $(".checkbox").prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
  $('.checkbox').on('click', function() {
    if ($('.checkbox:checked').length == $('.checkbox').length) {
      $('#check_all').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $('#check_all').prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
  
  // jquery code for display array :
  $("#hide").click(function() {
    var items = [];
    $("tr").each(function(i, r) {
      if (i > 0 && $(r).find(".checkbox").prop("checked")) {
        items.push({
          "nom": r.cells[1].innerText,
          "matricule": r.cells[2].innerText,
          "adresse": r.cells[3].innerText,
          "prime": $(r).find(".prime").val()
        })
      }
    });
    console.log(items);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered" id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th><input type="checkbox" id="check_all"></th>
    <th>nom</th>
    <th>matricule</th>
    <th>adresse</th>
    <th>prime</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
    <td>najib</td>
    <td>52</td>
    <td>tihit</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="prime" class="form-control prime" value="0"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
    <td>adil</td>
    <td>62</td>
    <td>tagmast</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="prime" class="form-control prime" value="0"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
    <td>hajar</td>
    <td>72</td>
    <td>tizgui</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="prime" class="form-control prime" value="0"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="form-group col-md-offset-5 ">
  <button class="btn btn-success add-all" type="submit" id="hide">Pointage men</button>
</div>
```

Summary of fixes:

- Added class `prime` to your `input name="prime"` elements

  - Preference, not necessary, can use `.find("input[name=prime])` instead below
- Adjusted lookup (`$(r).find("input").first()` to `$(r).find(".checkbox")`)
- Adjusted logic to pull value from input (`$(r).find(".prime").val()`)